# Script Active Directory for changing password of a user every week

Tags: powershell, active-directory, passwords

I am looking for a script to change the password from a user every week in Active Directory.

Should that we can change his password every week and that the password must be set to the first connection imagine on Monday.

Does anyone help me?

Thank you in advance and best regards !

Comment: How is the user going to know the password for the initial login Monday morning if it has been reset over the weekend?

Comment: What have you done so far? do you have any code?

Answer (score 0):

@Avshalom: I based it on:

```
Function Set-AdUserPwd{
param (
[string] $ user,
[string] $ pwd
) #end Param
$ oUser = [adsi] "LDAP: // $ user"
$ ouser.psbase.invoke ("SetPassword" $ pwd)
$ ouser.psbase.CommitChanges ()
} # Set-end function AdUserPwd
Set-AdUserPwd -user "cn = bob or HSG_TestOU =, dc = nwtraders, dc = com" -pwd P @ ssword1
```

@Mathias R. Jessen: We will have to define a base password so he could change on Monday morning

@ Frode F.: My English is very bad excuse me !

Comment: What about running your script as scheduled task on every week?